# Which is the best form builder?

Tags: forms

I'm pretty unsure which form builder I should use (Webform, Form Builder etc.)

Which one are you using? Which one is still updated and so on? I want to build a form and edit entries and show them on a drupal site.

Answer (score 4):

**Webform responses are NOT content!** Responses from the [webform](http://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module cannot be placed into pages on your site; only administrator users can see results (or specific user roles). You can put answers into Views. (Maybe now that is possible.)

What you want to consider is either [webform_entity](http://www.drupal.org/project/webform_entity) or the [EntityForms](http://drupal.org/project/entityforms) module. [When to use 1 of these modules is talked about on this docs page](http://drupal.org/node/1540680). These 2 modules make responses into entity content you can place as content on your site.

Also, webform_entity or entity_forms responses are NOT Drupal nodes; they are custom entities. You cannot moderate their content with say the [Workbench](http://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) module. Good luck auditing submissions before they are made live on your site.